# Data and Partitions Recovery after Clean command

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

Guys please i need help any suggestions on this post would be appreciated so i need to know if i can acutally restore my data since i lost it all while i was trying to install windows 7 on my computer there was a message telling that it was impossible to install windows on this partition so what i did was i used cmd command using shift andF10 and i selected the volume that i wanted to clean it all went that's actually what i thought however, what i did find out is that windows cleaned all my partitions and joined them into only one partition that merged all the partitions into one with all the store indicating no data sign so what i did was i processede into windows installation and when the installation completed and windows booted up i found my self completely lost since i found my without any of my previous data as a brand new with only windows files so what im asking please is a way to recover my data if there's anything possible i can do before it's too late please any help is appreciated .

Comment: Can you add proper punctuation & typography please.

Comment: Sorry i was just typing as fast as possible.

Comment: As you installed Windows over the `clean` ed area it is impossible to know what you can recover or even if you can recover anything meaningful. The linked questions all have some helpful comments and pointers but the first thing you have to do is stop running that computer. Every moment that the machine has booted from the newly installed operating system is a moment where more data is potentially being overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

You must debuging why is not possible install windows in this partition
1- check type partition . Windows just can be install in primary partition
2-please clear exact error . It often happend when prerequirment item for install windows not passed. 
 Errors often have code error and solution provided in support.microsoft.com

Comment: The Clean command was able to solve the issue of not installing windows but it deleted all my partitions and data and left me with a single partition to install windows in.

Comment: You have issue its about disk partition table or partition type . Clewn will remove all disk partition table and repartion your disk . This is very bad solution